# How to find Probability of three Systems

Tags: probability

Hi looking for a mathematical help here.

If there are 3 independent systems A, B & C. Each has wining rate of 60% & loosing rate of 40%.
Now I find following conditions. But for the rest need help.

Probability of loosing 3 systems all together = A ∩ B ∩ C = 29%
Probability of wining 3 systems all together = A ∩ B ∩ C = 5%

There is another way I saw on net is , probability of loosing 3 systems = 0.4*0.4*0.4 = 0.064
Probability of winning 3 systems = 0.6*0.6*0.6= 0.216

Which one is correct?

Probability of winning of 2 systems all together & losing 1 system = ??
Probability of losing of 2 systems all together & winning 1 system = ??

Thank you
Please share the formula also.

Comment: What you computed is wrong, net is right. It would be good if you explained what you did, so that the mistake can be pointed out.

Comment: I computed it using a on-line probability calculator. I understand now its wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an event with a probability of $p$ of success and $1-p$ of failure you are conducting a [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

When you add together independent identically distributed (iid) Bernoulli trials you get the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for which the probability mass function is:

$$Pr(X=k)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

For your case $n=3$, $p=0.6$

So, for 3 losses

$$Pr(X=0)={3\choose 0}0.6^0(1-0.6)^{3-0}=0.064$$

And, for 3 wins

$$Pr(X=3)={3\choose 3}0.6^3(1-0.6)^{3-3}=0.216$$

The rest I leave for you.

Comment: For the simple problems you tried, the net gave a simple way of solving using the *multiplicative principle*. For the ones where results are a mixture of "successes" and "failures", you will need the binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you Dale M for the detailed answer. It helped. I figure last two questions answer with the formula, there are total 8 combination. 3 combination for "1 win 2 loss" & 3 combination for "2 win 1 loss". So with the probability i multiplied with 3 & total probability for whole set, I got "1". So it done correctly.